# Exception occurred at Bank bank = new Bank(bankNaam);

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
```

I'm trying to create a constructor that can create an object of Bank, but i keep getting the error

> "Exception occurred at         Bank bank = new Bank(bankNaam);"

```
public class Bank
{
    // ArrayList variable van de klaas BankRekening
    private ArrayList<BankRekening> rekLijst;
    // Bank naam
    private String bankNaam = "ING";
    // Random getal generator
    private Random randomGenerator;


    /**
     * Dit creeert een nieuwe object en initialiseert de variabelen.
     */
    public Bank(String bankNaam)
    {
        // initialise instance variable
        Bank bank1 = new Bank(bankNaam);
        //rekLijst = new ArrayList<>();

    }




}
```

Comment: What's the point of `var bank = new Bank(bankNaam);`? it causes infinite recursion

Comment: Okay i will change it to to Bank so that it would be easier to read

Comment: You want to have the `var bank = new Bank(bankNaam);` **outside** the constructor, in code *using* the `Bank` class. (Perhaps in your `main` method, if this is for an assignment or similar.) If you call the constructor from within the constructor, it'll recurse until you run out of stack space.

Comment: I think you want `var bank = new Bank(bankNaam);` in the `public static void main()` method.

Comment: I'm using bluej so i don't need to declare it in the main() method

Comment: For the future, always post the whole error stacktrace - "Exception occurred at Bank bank = new Bank(bankNaam);" tells us nothing.

Comment: Thanks guys the problem is fixed. You guys were right i shouldn't try to call constructor in the same constructor. Thanks for all the help you guys are the best!!

Answer (score 2):

If you call the constructor from within the constructor, it'll recurse until you run out of stack space (because each call to the constructor calls the constructor again). You want to have the `var bank = new Bank(bankNaam);` **outside** the constructor, in code *using* the `Bank` class.

If this is for an assignment or similar, you'd probably have it in a `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    var bank = new Bank("ING");
    // ...
}
```

---

A couple of other notes:

- You also want to finish writing the constructor. Be sure to initialize all of your instance variables.
- You probably don't want to assign `"ING"` to `bankNaam` in its initializer. Instead, pass that into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign the value you can do this:

```
public Bank(String bankNaam){
  this.bankNaam = bankNaam;
}
```

If you really want to create object do it outside of the constructor. In addition you can create a `Test.java` file to test this.

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(string args[]){
      Bank bank1 = new Bank("ABC");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a constructor, a method that contructs your object:

```
public Bank(String bankNaam) {}
```

This is how you construct/initailize the object using the contrusctor:

```
Bank bank1 = new Bank(bankNaam);
```

You cannot contruct the object using the same contructor (you could use a different one though) because it will cause infinite recursion.

What you need is simply initialize the `Bank` object fields inside the constructor:

```
public Bank(String bankNaam) {
    this.bankNaam =  bankNaam;
}
```